# Using SQLite in android based devices

Tags: android, sqlite, storage, offline

Can we access SQLite DB from javascript(for offline use) in android based devices? I read here http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=809 that we can access it in apple's devices. [Or is the DB part of all HTML5 supporting browsers irrespective of the devices/OS?]

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about offline support within the apps? If yes, then here is a good tutorial

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

If not, please expand your question.

Comment: He's talking about javascript support from a browser, not within native apps

Comment: Andrew is right. Following is a brief description of the problem. I am looking for the possibility of accessing the DB from browser through javascript. I have a web application which stores offline data in the browser as javascript global variables(Is this so naive?). The app also uses jQuery extensively. For some reason, the app does not work properly in the iPhone. So i am planning to fix the issues one by one. To start with i am planning to move all offline data to the local DB in case the user is using a hand held device instead of a PC.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I hate to see something go unanswered. You should find examples of using HTML5 offline caching via JavaScript here:

http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=809